# A4 PageSize in CGSizeMake

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf

Im trying to make a PDF output that fills an A4 Page precisely, obviously creating the A4  page I'm using the CGSizeMake function. What is the correct numbers to input for an A4 page.

Everything i seem to try its either way to small or to big when trying to print.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `CGSizeMake(595, 842)` should work. PDF sizes are defined in points, with 72 points corresponding to one inch, so 595 points are ≈8.26 inches (≈210mm).